# How to dynamically choose a Rails model to instantiate?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oop

I have two "engines" that process a specific job, each one of them using different tools/apis. I have an `Engine` model that holds common data/behavior between them, but each `Engine` has other specific fields/methods.

```
class Engine
  field :name
  field :status
end

class DefaultEngine
  field :job_id

  def process
     # default engine process
     # ...
  end
end

class SpecialEngine

  def process
    # special engine process
    # ...
  end
end

class Site
  field :engine, type: String, default: '::DefaultEngine'
end
```

What I want to do is make `Engine` responsible for subclassing the correct engine, depending on the `site.engine` value. For example, in a controller I would want to do the following:

```
def start
  job = Engine.create()
  job.process
end
```

I don't want to reference neither engines directly. Instead, I want `Engine` to be responsible for figuring out which is the correct engine to use. What would be a way to handle this, so that `Engine.create` can return either an instance of `SpecialEngine` or `DefaultEngine`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Site
  field :engine, type: String, default: '::DefaultEngine'

  def engine_class
     @engine_class ||= engine.constantize
  end 
end
```

---

```
def start
  job = site.engine_class.create
  job.process
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Since this is marked `ruby-on-rails`, you can use `constantize`

```
site.engine # => 'SpecialEngine', your string field
site.engine.constantize # => SpecialEngine, class
site.engine.constantize.new # => #<SpecialEngine:0x007fc52c9893a8>, engine instance
```